# How to reverse an ArrayList from a file?

Tags: java, arraylist, input, reverse

This is the original question:

> Write a program that reads a set of doubles from a file, stores them in an array or ArrayList, and then prints them back out to the console (using System.out.println statements) in REVERSE order.
>
> For example, if the input file input.txt file contains
>
> 27.3
>   45.6
>   98.3
>   10.1
>
> The console output will display
>   10.1
>   98.3
>   45.6
>   27.3

And this is the code I have so far:

```
package reverse;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


   public class reversed {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner numFile = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    while (numFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = numFile.nextLine();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
        sc.useDelimiter(" ");
        while(sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            list.add(sc.nextDouble());
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    numFile.close();
    System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

How would I reverse the ArrayList I created? The code I have works, I just have no idea how to reverse it. And where exactly would I put that code? Thanks!

Comment: You do not need to actually reverse it - just print it backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to reverse the `ArrayList`, just iterate it in reverse order. Something like,

```
for (int i = list.size(); i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i - 1));
}
```

If you must reverse the `List` before iteration, you might use [`Collections.reverse(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-) like

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```